# make:auth not found in artisan command list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to generate an authentification module on laravel basing on this tutorial http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication, but this command is not working...

```
make:auth
```

the command line gives me this message

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "make:auth" is not defined
  Did you mean one of these?
      make:test
      make:request
      make:migration
      make:seeder
      make:middleware
      make:controller
      make:provider
      make:policy
      make:event
      make:console
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:model
      make:command
```

do you have any suggestions???

Regards

Comment: Which laravel version you use? Laravel 5.2?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"... so this is the problem .... I'll try to do an upgrade :) thanks

Comment: I als have version 5.1.* installed and I get the same error.. But the docs say it is as simple as doing this in cli `php artisan make:auth` How did you fix it? Can you upgrade to 5.2 yet? How?